# VS2015 QuickInfo colors

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-2015

Just imported [Son of obsidian](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian) theme into VS2015 Preview and I can´t see QuickInfo text anymore. Just searched for a way to change its bg color in Fonts and Colors options. There is any way to correct this?

[image: QuickInfo]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change tooltip background color in VS2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729553/change-tooltip-background-color-in-vs2015)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729553/change-tooltip-background-color-in-vs2015 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854630/how-to-set-tooltip-colors-in-vs2015 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570310/visual-studio-2015-tooltip-color