# How to set tooltip colors in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've just installed Visual Studio 2015.  Very nice overall, but the sheer vastness of different things you can configure under "Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors" has completely bamboozled me.

I need to find the setting that will allow me to change the colors for this tooltip, so that I can actually read it:

[image]

Where is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570310/visual-studio-2015-tooltip-color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the  The Color Theme Editor extension and is is possible....

[image: copy the theme you want]
[image: edit the new theme]

[image: show all elements]

[image: search for tooltip]

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: Nah, I don't want to start messing with new themes. I **like** my current colors.  I just want to be able to read my tool tips.

Comment: You don't need to. You start by copy the theme you use and then make that one change.

Comment: Then click "show all elements" and search for "tooltip"

Comment: Downloaded.  Where's "Show all elements"?  Perhaps you could put a screen shot in your answer?

Comment: OK, that was some pretty tacky screen dumping, but good enough to get you a bounty :-D

Comment: Really? I thought they were pretty :)

Comment: @iCediCe That won't help because those colors are taken directly from the individual keyword colors. So if his keywords are yellow then so will the color of the keyword in the tooltip be, unfortunately. The tooltip colors you can edit is the color of the rest of the text.